# Testing AngularJS 1.6 class-based controllers with Jasmine/Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to use jasmine/karma to test my class-based controllers with no luck... All the examples I'm seeing are from 2014 or older. I've loaded the angular, and angular-mock file in my karma files. Plunker code: https://plnkr.co/edit/TCXW3rIUqV8OmbzzhDhn?p=catalogue

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
            './node_modules/angular/angular.js',
    './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js',
    './node_modules/jquery-slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js',
    './node_modules/satellizer/dist/satellizer.js',
    './node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js',
    './node_modules/oclazyload/dist/ocLazyLoad.js',
    './node_modules/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-bootstrap/dist/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
    './node_modules/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
    './node_modules/moment/moment.js',
    './node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js',
    './node_modules/block-ui/jquery.blockUI.js',
    './node_modules/js-cookie/src/js.cookie.js',
    './node_modules/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
    './node_modules/angular-websocket/dist/angular-websocket.js',
    './node_modules/bootstrap-switch/dist/js/bootstrap-switch.js',
    './node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js',
    './node_modules/ng-file-upload/dist/ng-file-upload.js',
    './node_modules/angular-smart-table/dist/smart-table.js',
    './node_modules/ng-toast/dist/ngToast.js',
    './node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
    './node_modules/progressbar.js/dist/progressbar.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js',
    './node_modules/angular-ui-grid/ui-grid.js',
    './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
    './node_modules/@uirouter/angularjs/release/stateEvents.min.js',
    './node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
    './src/main.js',
    './src/components/users/users.spec.js',
],


// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: [
],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {
},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false,

// Concurrency level
// how many browser should be started simultaneous
concurrency: Infinity
})
}
```

users.spec.js

```
describe('User component', () => {
let element, scope;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('MetronicApp'));

beforeEach(inject((_$rootScope_, _$compile_) => {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
}));

it('should return the name of the user', () => {
    var ctrl = $componentController('UsersController');
    const user = {
        userType: 'Person'
    };
    expect(ctrl.getFullName(user)).toEqual('Person')
})
});
```

component

```
/**
 * @name MetronicApp.component:users
 *
 * @description <users> component, users page displaying all current portal users
 */
class UsersController {
constructor($rootScope, $uibModal) {
    this.$rootScope = $rootScope;
    this.$uibModal = $uibModal;
}

$onChanges() {
    setTimeout(() => { App.initAjax() }, 0);

    this.$rootScope.settings.layout.pageContentWhite = false;
    this.$rootScope.settings.layout.pageBodySolid = true;
    this.$rootScope.settings.layout.pageSidebarClosed = false;
}

$onInit() {
    this.users = this.users.users.filter(user => user.userType !== 'admin');
}

$onDestroy() {}

getFullName(user) {
    switch (user.userType) {
        case 'person':
            return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
        case 'company':
            return user.corpName;
        case 'staff':
            return `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`;
        case 'admin':
            return user.firstName;
        default :
            return 'UNKNOWN'
    }
};

hasPortalAccess(user) {
    return (user.isPortalUser) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
}

getPermissions (user) {
    switch (user.userType) {
        case 'person':
            return 'Person';
        case 'company':
            return 'Company';
        case 'staff':
            return 'Staff';
        case 'admin':
            return 'Admin';
        default :
            return 'UNKNOWN'
    }
}
}

const users = {
bindings: {
    user: '<',
    users: '<'
},
controller: UsersController,
controllerAs: 'usersCtrl',
templateUrl: 'src/components/users/users.html'
};

angular
.module('MetronicApp')
.component('users', users);
```

I'm trying to test this component's method but I'm (updated) getting this error now

```
        Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'UsersController' is not registered.
        http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.7/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=UsersController
        at node_modules/angular/angular.js:116:12
        at $controller (node_modules/angular/angular.js:11041:17)
        at node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2314:14
        at UserContext.inject (src/components/users/users.spec.js:17:16)
        at Object.invoke (node_modules/angular/angular.js:5097:19)
        at UserContext.WorkFn (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3183:20)
    Error: Declaration Location
        at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3146:25)
        at Suite.describe (src/components/users/users.spec.js:16:16)
        at src/components/users/users.spec.js:1:1
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'getFullName' of undefined
        at UserContext.it (src/components/users/users.spec.js:25:21)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`module` global is used for CommonJS modules in modular environment.

[`angular.mock.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module) is unshortened synonym to AngularJS `module` that should be used in this case.

Comment: I get this error now. So I have to require angular in the file? 

Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3) User component encountered a declaration exception FAILED
        ReferenceError: angular is not defined
            at UserContext.beforeEach (src/components/users/users.spec.js:5:9)
        ReferenceError: inject is not defined
            at Suite.describe (src/components/users/users.spec.js:10:5)
            at src/components/users/users.spec.js:1:1
Chrome 64.0.3282 (Mac OS X 10.13.3): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.03 secs / 0.022 secs)

Comment: You should include angular, and you're already doing this in Karma config `files`. So I'd expect it to work. Make sure that your config corresponds to the one you've posted. Notice that there's no app loaded in `files`, so there are no controllers you're trying to test.

Comment: I've marked your original answer as accepted as it solved my initial issue. Again, Thank you